# a single word for "much in a short period"

Tags: word-request

I came across a word for that meaning once but it just slipped my mind. All I remember now is this incomplete example

> Regular exercise is better than ...... strenuous exercise.

I'm not sure if the word I saw is an adverb, because I don't remember the exact example. I'm glad with any words regardless of parts of speech.

Comment: If you'd settle for a phrase, you could say "a burst of".

Comment: Possible antonyms of **regular**: occasional, sporadic, irregular, infrequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Regular exercise is better than **(occasional) bouts** of strenuous exercise.

**bout** - a short period of intense activity of a specified kind [Source of meaning](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=bout%20meaning). Also, [the exact sentence is present here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bout).

> Regular exercise is better than **a burst of** strenuous exercise.

**a burst of** - a sudden increase in something, especially for a short period [Source of meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/burst) (credits to @JavaLatte, because he said it first)

> Regular exercise is better than **a flurry of** strenuous exercise.

**a flurry of** - a sudden, short period of activity, excitement, or interest [Source of meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flurry)

> Regular exercise is better than **rounds** of strenuous exercise. (*not very relevant, but can be used*)

**round/rounds** - a number of things or group of events (done successively) [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/round?q=round%20of)